# Making longest line in 10 by 10 grid

Tags: pattern, combinatorics, optimization

How many blocks can you pass through at most in a 10 × 10 grid.

The rules are:

> 1. You cannot go over a line
> 2. You cannot lift the pencil
> 3. You cannot allow the blocks you have passed through to make a 2×2 block of adjacent boxes

I think it would be 71.

[image]

Comment: It can be 75 in a sense that 100-(5*5)

Comment: Excuse my humor - but you violated your own rules (no lifting the pencil - I see it happen at least 2 times ) *g*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the problem via integer linear programming, and

> 71 is indeed optimal. Here's another optimal solution:

[image]

Here are optimal values for $n\times n$ grids with $n \le 10$:
\begin{matrix}
n &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10 \\
\hline
\text{maximum} &1 &3 &8 &12 &19 &25 &37 &45 &59 &71 \\
\end{matrix}

By the way, you lifted your pencil in row 1, column 4. :)

Comment: actually he lifted the pencil 2 times^^ 1 further lift in row 3 column 6

Comment: @eagle275, that one was a little ambiguous, so I didn't want to falsely accuse. :)

Answer (score 9):

> If diagonals are allowed, here is a solution with 75. 
>  [image: grid]

Comment: OCD doesn't like your yellow dots not being all in order.

Comment: @DanielMathias It was bothering me too that I started it like that. I have updated it to have a cleaner solution.

Comment: Your solution offers up a maximum bound: since 1 out of every 4 squares has to be omitted, that means that the upper bound cannot be higher than 75%, which would be 75 out of the 100 boxes.